# Set Permissions of a file using Windows API

Tags: winapi, file-permissions, ntfs

I need to Set permission from a Web Application. For that I'm using Java for backend and ember js for frontend. For getting and setting the permission, I'm using C++ combined with Windows API using Java Native Interface. Now my problem is,

When I Set Permission locally, It works fine. But when I set permission from the server side, It returns the error as **SetNamedSecurityInfo Error : 5 , Error : 1008** . Please let me know what is the issue and how to correct it. I'm new to Windows API so I'm using code from the internet and modifying it to my needs.(Also Please explain the process, If there are any other way please suggest me that too)

Thanks in Advance.

Here is the program,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <aclapi.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <tchar.h>


using namespace std;

DWORD AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor(
     LPTSTR pszObjName,          // name of object
     SE_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType,  // type of object     
     DWORD dwAccessRights,       // access mask for new ACE
     ACCESS_MODE AccessMode,     // type of ACE
     DWORD dwInheritance         // inheritance flags for new ACE
 )
 {
     DWORD dwRes = 0;
     PACL pOldDACL = NULL, pNewDACL = NULL;
     PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
     EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;

     if (NULL == pszObjName)
         return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;

     // Get a pointer to the existing DACL.

     dwRes = GetNamedSecurityInfo(pszObjName, ObjectType,
         DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
         NULL, NULL, &pOldDACL, NULL, &pSD);

     if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes) {
         printf("GetNamedSecurityInfo Error %u\n", dwRes);
         goto Cleanup;
     }


     // Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for the new ACE. 

     ZeroMemory(&ea, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
     ea.grfAccessPermissions = dwAccessRights;
     ea.grfAccessMode = AccessMode;
     ea.grfInheritance = dwInheritance;
     ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_NAME;
     ea.Trustee.ptstrName = _T("CURRENT_USER");
     ea.Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_USER;
     // Create a new ACL that merges the new ACE
     // into the existing DACL.

     dwRes = SetEntriesInAcl(1, &ea, pOldDACL, &pNewDACL);
     if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes) {
         printf("SetEntriesInAcl Error %u\n", dwRes);
         goto Cleanup;
     }

     // Attach the new ACL as the object's DACL.

     dwRes = SetNamedSecurityInfo(pszObjName, ObjectType,
         DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
         NULL, NULL, pNewDACL, NULL);
     if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes) {
         printf("SetNamedSecurityInfo Error %u\n", dwRes);
         goto Cleanup;
     }

 Cleanup:

     if (pSD != NULL)
         LocalFree((HLOCAL)pSD);
     if (pNewDACL != NULL)
         LocalFree((HLOCAL)pNewDACL);

     return dwRes;
 }



bool grantAccess(std::string file, int permissionval) {
    
    DWORD grant = 0;

    unsigned int permissionset = 0x00;


    if ((permissionval & 1) == 1) {
        permissionset |= FILE_GENERIC_WRITE;
    }
    if ((permissionval & 2) == 2) {
        permissionset |= FILE_GENERIC_READ;
    }
    if ((permissionval & 4) == 4) {
        permissionset |= FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE;
    }
    if ((permissionval & 8) == 8) {
        permissionset |= FILE_ALL_ACCESS;
    }
    if (permissionval == 0) {
        permissionset |= NOT_USED_ACCESS;
    }
  
    LPTSTR lpfile = new TCHAR[31];
    lpfile = (LPTSTR) file.c_str();

      DWORD dwres1 = AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor(
         lpfile,
         SE_FILE_OBJECT,
         permissionset,
         SET_ACCESS,
         NO_INHERITANCE);

     if (dwres1 == ERROR_SUCCESS)
     {
         return TRUE;
     }
     else
     {
         std::cout << "Error   :   " << GetLastError() << '\n';
     }
     return FALSE;
}

int main() {
    bool g = grantAccess("C:/Users/Vicky/Desktop/samples/sample2.txt", 3);
    
    if (g)
    {
        cout << "File access granted" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

While Running Locally, The Permission is set to Read and Write for this program.

But When running from tomcat server, The below error is shown,

**SetNamedSecurityInfo Error 5**
**Error   :   1008**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Error code [1008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-) is `ERROR_NO_TOKEN` ("An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist."). Though it's unclear whether that error code is even meaningful. You are calling [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) at a time where there are literally **no** guarantees at all that it would return a meaningful value. May want to fix that before moving forward.

Comment: Yes When I looked into official docs, It said the same thing. But I need to know how to resolve this, as I'm new to this windows api I can't understand. So Please let me know what to change or modify. I'll try to understand it better. Thank you.

Comment: @Siva As IInspectable said, you are misusing `GetLastError()`. When `AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor()` returns an error. `grantAccess()` should be logging the value of `dwres1` instead of calling `GetLastError()`.

Comment: @Siva Another thing - you are type-casting a `std::string::c_str()` pointer to `TCHAR*` (and causing a memory leak, too). That cast is very suspicious, you should NEVER do that. If you are compiling for `UNICODE`, that cast is plain wrong, you need an actual data conversion from `char[]` to `wchar_t[]` via `MultiByteToWideChar()` or equivalent. And if you are not compiling for `UNICODE`, the cast is redundant. So, you should get rid of the cast and pass the `c_str()` pointer as-is to `AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor()`. If it fails to compile, fix the root problem, don't hide it with a cast.